# Django: Return all books authored by all authors

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have these models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
#id         = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
code            = models.CharField(verbose_name="Author Code", max_length=100, unique=True)
firstname   = models.CharField(verbose_name="First Name", max_length=200)
lastname        = models.CharField(verbose_name="Last Name",max_length=200)

#Optional Fields
middlename  = models.CharField(verbose_name="Middlename", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
email       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Author's Email",max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
sex         = models.CharField(verbose_name="Sex", max_length=1, choices=(('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female')), null=True, blank=True)
salutation  = models.CharField(verbose_name="Salutation",max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
suffix      = models.CharField(verbose_name="Suffix", max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s %s (%s)' % (self.firstname, self.lastname, self.code)


class Book(models.Model):
#book title
#book_id                = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
title           = models.CharField(verbose_name="Book Title", max_length=200)
subtitle        = models.CharField(verbose_name="Book Subtitle", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

#Reference information
accession_number    = models.CharField(verbose_name="Accession Number", max_length=100)
call_number = models.CharField(verbose_name="Call Number", max_length=100)
isbn            = models.CharField(verbose_name="ISBN Code", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, unique=False)
dewey_class = models.ForeignKey(DeweyClass, verbose_name="Dewey Class", null=True, default=False, unique=False)
subject     = models.CharField(verbose_name="Subject", max_length=100)

#authorship information
author          = models.ManyToManyField(Author, verbose_name="Book Author")
pages           = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Number of Pages")
edition     = models.CharField(verbose_name="Edition", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
volumes     = models.CharField(verbose_name="Volume Number", max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

#

Now, in the front-end, I want to display a list of authors, together with the Books they made.

something like this:

J.R.R. Tolkien

- The Lord Of The Rings
- The Hobbit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *regroup* template tag : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

in your view:

```
books_qs = Book.objects.all()

books = []
for book in books_qs:
    for author in book.author.all():
        books.append({'title' : book.title, 'author' : author.lastname})
```

in your template:

```
{% regroup books by author as author_list %}

<ul>
{% for author in author_list %}
   <li>{{ author.grouper}}
   <ul>
    {% for item in author.list %}
      <li>{{ item.title}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This tag seems to work only on lists.

I want to achieve something like this:

http://lms.ndmc.edu.ph/opac/authors/?q=A

Comment: regroup tag does work on querysets too. In your example it doesn't work because the relation between author and book is ManyToMany field. If you can switch to a ForeignKey field you're done, otherwise in your view you have to transform the queryset into the appropriate list.

Comment: I have updated my answer to make it work with M2M relations